# How to exclude children of selected parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a HUD display on the bottom of my game. To the right of the HUD bar will be a nested minimap.

When I hover over the HUD, it will increase opacity of the

When I click on the minimap (child of HUD), it will expand a larger map. When I click on the HUD (parent element), it will apply the opacity rule with `toggleClass()`.

I don't want this opacity rule to be applied when I click on the child `minimap` though, only when I click on the parent `HUD`. Right now it's being applied when I click on parent and child.

See [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ciwojifiba/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

HTML

```
       <div id="HUD">
          <div id="map"></div>  
       </div>
```

JS

```
       $("#HUD").click(function(){
            $(this).toggleClass("HUDactive");
       });
```

CSS

```
#HUD {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 15%;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: thin solid darkgray;   
    opacity: 0.3;
    background-color: black;
    transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}

#HUD:hover {
    border-top: thin solid snow;   
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.HUDactive {
    opacity: 0.8 !important;
}

#map {

    color: red;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    background-color: gray;
    height: 100%;
    width: 15%;
    float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Javascript a concept called "event bubbling" occurs. When you click on an element the events registered to that element occur first. Once they are completed, the event travels to the parent, and so on. You can use this to your advantage in this case, by stopping the event at the "#map" element.

Jquery has a handy way of doing this using [stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/).

Just add this code to your example:

```
$("#map").on('click', function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether the click was happened in the `#map` element like

```js
$("#HUD").click(function(e) {
  //if #map don't have any descendants then
  //if (!$(e.target).is('#map')) {
  if (!$(e.target).closest('#map').length) {
    $(this).toggleClass("HUDactive");
  }
});
```

```css
#HUD {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 15%;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: thin solid darkgray;
  opacity: 0.3;
  background-color: black;
  transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}
#HUD:hover {
  border-top: thin solid snow;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.HUDactive {
  opacity: 0.8 !important;
}
#map {
  color: red;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100%;
  width: 15%;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="HUD">
  <div id="map"></div>
</div>
```